# How to Convert 2-D array into Image in c#

Tags: c#

I have a 2D array of integers in c#.

Each entry in the 2-D array correspond to a pixel value

How can i make this 2-D array into an image file (in C#)

Thanks

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Here is a very fast, albeit unsafe, way of doing it:

*[Edit] This example took  0.035 ms*

```
// Create 2D array of integers
int width = 320;
int height = 240;
int stride = width * 4;
int[,] integers = new int[width,height];

// Fill array with random values
Random random = new Random();
for (int x = 0; x < width; ++x)
{
    for (int y = 0; y < height; ++y)
    {
        byte[] bgra = new byte[] { (byte)random.Next(255), (byte)random.Next(255), (byte)random.Next(255), 255 };
        integers[x, y] = BitConverter.ToInt32(bgra, 0);
    }
}

// Copy into bitmap
Bitmap bitmap;
unsafe
{
    fixed (int* intPtr = &integers[0,0])
    {
        bitmap = new Bitmap(width, height, stride, PixelFormat.Format32bppRgb, new IntPtr(intPtr));
    }
}
```

and the result:

[image: result]

Comment: Good example, but the image does not look random :)

Comment: :) you're right, I see it too... since the C# `Random` class is based on a definite mathematical algorithm I guess it shouldn't be all that surprising.

Comment: Good example, but this shows a 1-dimensional array, not 2-D as requested.

Comment: nice!  but now, what if it's an array of arrays, not a 2d array?  :)

Answer (score 0):

If you have the need for speed look at [my Kinect sample](http://blog.tedd.no/index.php/2011/02/01/early-alpha-release-kinect-c-starter-kit/). Basically it creates a memory area and uses an unsafe pointer to generate an Int32 array towards the memory. A BitmapSource object is used to map a bitmap (image) directly onto the same area. This particular example also uses unmanaged memory to make it compatible with P/Invoke.

[This blogpost](http://davidthomasbernal.com/blog/2008/03/13/c-image-processing-performance-unsafe-vs-safe-code-part-i/) describes the difference in performance of using unsafe. 
Part from that have a look at:

- http://www.bytemycode.com/snippets/snippet/412/
- http://www.jmsoftware.co.uk/blog/c-snippet-for-accessing-bitmap-data-with-unsafe-code
- http://www.vcskicks.com/fast-image-processing.php

Note that you can just as well make a Int32[]-pointer instead of the examples which uses Byte[]-pointer.

Answer (score 0):

If speed is not a concern - Bitmap + SetPixel and than save to a file: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.bitmap.setpixel.aspx

Comment: Easy, but as you mention: slow. Amazingly slow! :)

Answer (score 0):

[`Bitmap.LockBits`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.bitmap.lockbits.aspx) should work, if you're wanting a WinForms image.

Comment: @ozcanovunc: The grammar was perfect already.  You may want to read about the present progressive tense.

Answer (score 0):

Would projecting the array into a base64 string for streaming into a `Bitmap` be slow too?